# SAS SYSDate format in PROC SQL

Tags: sas, datepart, sysdate

When I try to use `Sysdate / Today()` for my PROC SQL QUERY condition like 
`Table_Date + 60 > Today()`, it is returning a number value 20560. Can you please advise how can I convert that number to a date time.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking (conditions like that evaluate to true / false, not a number, also you appear to be talking about a date not a datetime).  Can you provide an example of your code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the way the data is displayed in the table following your `proc sql;` query, try applying a format as follows:

```
proc sql;
create table want as
  select Table_Date + 60 as my_date_col format=date9.  
  from have
  where Table_Date + 60 > Today();
```

SAS stores dates as the number of days since Jan 1st, 1960.  To display that number as a 'readable date' you can apply one of a number of [date formats](http://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/lrcon/zenid-63.htm) as per the `format=` syntax above.

Note that date formats are different from datetime formats - which work on an underlying value of number of seconds since 01JAN1960.

If you do wish to convert your date to a datetime (as per the wording of the question) you can simply multiply the value by 24 (hrs), 60 (mins) and 60 (secs) as follows:

```
proc sql;
create table want as
  select (Table_Date + 60) * 24 * 60 * 60 as my_datetime_col format=datetime19.  
  from have
  where Table_Date + 60 > Today();
```